# Loopback default models with a mysql database

Tags: express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying out loopback and noticed that in the `model-config` file it has a reference to 5 models that have their `dataSource` set to the memory database `db`:

```
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  }
```

Is that desired behaviour to keep the users, acl etc in the memory? If not, how can I port those models to `mysql`? I tried switching the `dataSource` to my `mysql` source but the server complains because the tables are not present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy paste the following code in server/server.js. (preferably to the last)

```
var appModels = ['User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];

var ds = app.dataSources.mysqlDS;
ds.isActual(appModels, function(err, actual) {
  if (!actual) {
    ds.autoupdate(appModels, function(err) {
      if (err) throw (err);
    });
  }
});
```

Don't forget to change the model's datasource to the new datasource in model-config.json. In the code replace the mysqlDS to your datasource.

Cheers!

Reference:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-database-tables-for-built-in-models.html

Comment: This saves my day. Thanks @Anoop.P.A

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a migration.  Check out the docs for [auto-migrate](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+a+database+schema+from+models#Creatingadatabaseschemafrommodels-Auto-migrate) but the easiest solution (no coding) is to use [strongloop arc](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIS/Creating+and+editing+models#Creatingandeditingmodels-Migratingamodel).

To code it you could drop an auto-migration into a boot script, like `dataSource.automigrate();` which would build the tables however that would also drop any existing data you have.

Comment: I looked into the `arc` interface and there's no reference to those models. How could I migrate them from `arc`?

Comment: You can see more info about migrating models in arc n the documentation here http://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIS/Creating+and+editing+models

Answer (score -1):

Add these table in MySql Database:-

```
    CREATE TABLE `AccessToken` (
    `id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `ttl` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `scopes` TEXT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `userId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `ACL` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `model` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `property` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `accessType` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `permission` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `principalType` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `principalId` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `Role` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `RoleMapping` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `principalType` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `principalId` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `roleId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `principalId` (`principalId`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `User` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `realm` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    `emailVerified` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `verificationToken` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```